# Cryptonight V7 mining issues

Tags: cryptonight

I'm having a bit of problem here. As you all know, Cryptonight V7 is more profitable than v6 after the monero hardfork, I started trying to mine with this algo in Nicehash.But I got an error. The Nicehash Legacy was showing 0 H/s in total (GPU+CPU) & XMR showed 0 H/s in only gpu but mining with CPU.[image] so I reinstalled Nicehash Legacy. But this time the GPU can not be benchmarked. Though it had abnormal spikes in GPU usage.[image] Then I used SRBminer-CN. It also had 0 H/s after a few minutes & the same identical spike i had when benching XMR stak in Nicehash.[image]Then I switched to XMR stak (non NH). But no luck. It mines, gets new jobs from pool but result accepted by pool is one or two .( I'm confused in this. Does it still mining or not. Because I don't get a penny if the result is not accepted by the pool.)[image].At last I tried Claymore CryptoNote AMD GPU Miner v11.3. This one mines pretty good but the total share is 0.[image]So I'm not so sure about this one that is this still mining or not..Hopes somebody can help me out.

Thank you all.